# How to align a text to the top of another character?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, text-alignment, flutter-row

I would like to align one set of numbers to the top of another set of numbers, just as the smallest currency units that can be found on some price tags.

[image]

I've placed two `Text` inside a `Row` with `CrossAxisAlignment.start` but I can't get them both to be the same height.

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(
      '409',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      '00',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not yet supported in Flutter - See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80. You can still achieve what you want by adding some top-padding to your superscripted text, but the padding would need to change depending on the size of the font.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `RichText` for it. You can use `WidgetSpan` to align the text to the  top.

You can take reference from the sample code below:

```
RichText(
              text: const TextSpan(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), children: [
                WidgetSpan(
                    alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.top,
                    child: Text(
                      '\$',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    )),
                TextSpan(text: '400'),
                WidgetSpan(
                    alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.top,
                    child: Text(
                      '00',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    )),
              ]),
            )
```

And output is below:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

It caused `Text` widget has padding. The padding is needeed if you type some character like below.

```
Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text(
                  'Ğ ğ, H h, X x, I ı, İ i',
                   style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                 ),
             ),
     ),
```

[image]

May this is not the best practice to achieve what you want. You can try this code by setting `height` to `0.8` or other value.

```
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text(
                '409',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 20,
                   height: 0.8,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Text(
                 '00',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 12,
                   height: 0.8,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                 ),
          ),
        ),
      ]
  ),
```

[image]